# Get val from input and ignore the space

Tags: jquery

I have this input:

```
<input class='name'></input>
```

Let's say that we are typing this: 'John Doe Doo' in the input.

if I use jQuery `$('.name').val().split(' ')` and the input contains space at the end, jQuery will see it as a block of text.

Another problem is that I don't know how to get the fist block of text and then the other two or more (and to ignore the space at the end).

My final result should be:

```
var name = Johh
var lname = Doe Doe
```

Any ideas? I've tried something with `$.trim` but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid

Comment: an `input` tag is self closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var split = $( '.name' ).val().split( ' ' );

var name  = split[ 0 ];
var lname = split.slice( 1 ).join( ' ' );
```

[Here's an interactive demo](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/w9JfG/).

Answer (score 1):

For avoiding white space at end and start you can use `trim()`

```
var data=$('.name').val().trim();
```

For splitting it and getting fname and lname variable

```
var data=$('.name').val().trim();
var split=data.split(' ');
var fname=split[0];
var lname=split[1]+' '+split[2];
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/vVwr9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use split, then recombine the array:

```
var temp = $('.name').val().trim().split(' ');
var name = (temp.length ? temp[0] : '');
var lname = '';
if(temp.length>1) {
    temp = temp.slice(1); // everything from index 1 onwards
    lname = temp.join(' '); // rebuild the rest of the data.
}
```

Results:

```
name == "John"
lname == "Doh Doe"
```

[**Fiddle or it didn't happen**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/29dbr/)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove space from start and end by using this method given below.
Suppose your string is

```
var testString= " Vishal Singh Gehlot ";
testString= testString.replace(/\s+$/, '');
```

Then split this string by space like this

```
var NewString = testString.split(' ');
var  name = NewString[0]; 
var lname = NewString[1]+" "+NewString[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var temp = $('.name').val().trim();
 var firstSpace = temp.indexOf(' ');
 // it will be the index of first space.

 var firstName = temp.substring(0,firstSpace );
 var lastName = temp.substring(firstSpace +1 ,temp.length);
```